# Remove Date When Name Removed

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that automatically enters date + 3 days in specific cell when a name is entered in another cell. See coding below. What I need is code to add to this that will remove date when name is removed.

```vb
'When name entered in H34 date + 3 days is entered in H37

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Auto fills Shipment Required By date in H37 When Name
    'entered in H34 under Submitted BY
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H34:H34")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(4, 1)     ' Adjust numbers to match cell for date to go into -currently H37
            .Value = Date + 3 'this will use date when name is entered into Order Submitted By cell  and add 3 days
                              'Add .EntireColumn.AutoFit to fit data to cells. Does not work on merged cells
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Need to add code to clear date in H37 when name removed from H34

Have tried this but it does not work. Different code construction from my original

```vb
If Sheets("OrderForm").Range("H34") = "" Then
    Sheets("OrderForm").Range("H37").ClearContents
End if
```

Comment: This code worked just as my original code did. Still have to select G37+Ctrl+H37+Delete to remove autofilled date.

Comment: This may be because I have another code to prohibited selection of H37 so date can't be removed. Have to use ....G37+Ctrl+H37+Delete to remove autofilled date.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows a quick check to see if the cell has a name or not:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Auto fills Shipment Required By date in H37 When Name
    'entered in H34 under Submitted BY
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H34:H34")) Is Nothing Then
        '--- check if the name is there or not
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            '--- we have a name, so adjust numbers to match
            '    cell for date to go into -currently H37
            With Target(4, 1)
                .Value = Date + 3
            End With
        Else
            '--- name has been deleted, so remove the date
            With Target(4, 1)
                .Value = vbNullString
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```